# Mismatch data in Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I`m a newbie to SQL world, Can someone help me out with this.

I have two tables with same columns, CID, Amount. Both have a different logic on how the data is inserted but technically both tables should have same amount of CID's in count.

In my case I do have same count for given period, however I believe the Amount is a mismatched.

I want to identify which CID`s have wrong Amount and escalate this issue to Level 4 to see the business logic.

Can someone show me how can I find the mismatched?

When I did:

```
select count(CID) from Table A
union all 
select count(CID) from table B
```

I get 1000 on both select.

Comment: Of course we could try to guess what you want, but how about you delivering at least an example input with desired output?

Answer (score 1):

a quick little example...

```
create table tempA (CID int);
create table tempB (CID int);

insert into tempA values (1); 
insert into tempA values (2); 
insert into tempA values (2); 

insert into tempB values (1); 
insert into tempB values (2); 
insert into tempB values (3); 

mysql> select * from tempA;
+------+
| CID  |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    2 |
+------+

mysql> select * from tempB;
+------+
| CID  |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
+------+

select case when tempA_ct.CID is not null then tempA_ct.CID 
                                          else tempB_ct.CID end as CID, 

       case when a_CID_ct is null then 0 else a_CID_ct end as CID_A_count,

       case when b_CID_ct is null then 0 else b_CID_ct end as CID_B_count 

from   (select CID, count(CID) as a_CID_ct 
        from   tempA 
        group  by CID) as tempA_ct

        full outer join (
              select CID, count(CID) as b_CID_ct 
              from   tempB
              group  by CID) as tempB_ct
           on tempB_ct.CID=tempA_ct.CID 


CID     CID_A_COUNT     CID_B_COUNT
1       1               1
2       2               1
3       0               1
4       1               0
```

this can also be written as:

```
select CID,
       sum(case when tbln='A' then 1 else 0 end) as a_count, 
       sum(case when tbln='B' then 1 else 0 end) as b_count 
from   (select CID, 'A' as tbln 
        from tempA 
        union all 
        select CID, 'B' as tbln 
        from tempB) as joined
group  by CID        

+------+---------+---------+
| CID  | a_count | b_count |
+------+---------+---------+
|    1 |       1 |       1 |
|    2 |       2 |       1 |
|    3 |       0 |       1 |
|    4 |       1 |       0 |
+------+---------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic, please go through some tutorials later, for now
Try this

If you are sure that you have same number of records in both tables then following simple sql will work.
If you have different CIDs in both the tables then you need to use Left and right outer join to find them out.

```
select a.CID, a.amount 'TableA_amt', b.amount 'TableB_amt' 
from TableA A inner join TableB B 
ON a.CID=b.CID
Where a.amount <> b.amount
```